# boost::asio::read function hanging

Tags: c++, boost-asio

If someone could please help me out, I cannot understand how the boost::asio::read function works in boost asio.  In boost's example they have it declare the buffer size before the message is received which makes no sense (how do I know how many bytes to read before I read the message?)

I tried this code but it just hangs

```
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;

  tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
  tcp::resolver::query query(tcp::v4(), "localhost", "3000");
  tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

  tcp::socket sock(io_service);
  boost::asio::connect(sock, iterator);
  cout << "read start" << endl;
  boost::system::error_code err_code;

  // Read from client.
  boost::asio::streambuf read_buffer;
  int bytes_transferred = boost::asio::read(sock, read_buffer, err_code);
  std::cout << "Read: " << make_string(read_buffer) << std::endl;
  read_buffer.consume(bytes_transferred); // Remove data that was read.
```

Comment: Is it 'hanging' or is it _waiting for more data to come in_?

Comment: it is waiting on data to come in, but how can I tell it the amount of bytes to read BEFORE i read it?

Comment: This is a screwy aspect of sockets (and TCP/IP). They can't tell you how many bytes of data are inbound. You must use the nature of the protocol to tell. If you create your own protocol, you should have some end-of-message pattern (e.g., "\n") or a message header that indicates how many bytes will follow.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you know how much bytes you want to read from the definition of protocol.

In the opposite case you have to read **bytes one by one** and observe the error code to stop at the end of connection, file, etc.

Synchronous methods (for example `read`) in Boost.Asio are nice for short examples, but in practical use cases you should prefer the asynchronous version [`async_read`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read.html), which allows you to **cancel** or just **wait for a next chunk of data without blocking** your program.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same problem. It seems that boost::asio::read is supposed to be hang there until the connected client is closed. Instead, you can use `socket.read_some` like this:

```
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
try {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 9999));

    for (;;) {
        tcp::socket socket(io_service);
        acceptor.accept(socket);

        std::string message = "server received!\n";

        boost::system::error_code error_code;
        boost::asio::streambuf stream_buf;

        std::vector<char> buf(1024);
        size_t len = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf), error_code);
        std::string received_filename(buf.begin(), buf.end());
        received_filename.resize(len);
        if (error_code) {
            std::cout << "error status: " << error_code.message() << std::endl;
        }

        boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(message), error_code);
        if (error_code) {
            std::cout << "error status: " << error_code.message() << std::endl;
        }
        query_database(tree, received_filename, output_folder, db_image_filenames);
    }
}
catch (std::exception& e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

This will get the message from the client instantly with a relative short message. Hope this help.