# Boost asio io_content run non-blocking

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, blocking, boost-beast

Currently i am writing a C++ Websocket Client Library which get wrapped in a C# Library.
I am using Boost Beast for the websocket connection.
Now i am at the point that i start a async_read when the handshake is completed so the websocket dont disconnect.
The Problem is the io_content blocks the thread so the C# program stops excecuting until the async_read gets a timeout and the io_content returns. But i want that the C# program keep executing.
I tried to execute the connect function in a thread, but there's the problem, that the next function that the C# program calls is a write operation and it crashes, because the connect function is still connecting...

library.cpp:

```cpp
void OpenConnection(char* id)
{
    std::cout << "Opening new connection..." << std::endl;
    std::shared_ptr<Session> session = std::make_shared<Session>();
    session->connect();
    sessions.emplace(std::string(id), std::move(session));
}
```

session.cpp:

```cpp
void Session::connect()
{
    resolver.async_resolve(
        "websocket_uri",
        "443",
        beast::bind_front_handler(
            &Session::on_resolve,
            shared_from_this()));
    ioc.run();
}
```

The on_resolve,on_connect,on_handshake... are the same as here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/beast/example/websocket/client/async-ssl/websocket_client_async_ssl.cpp

Unless the on_handshake function:

```cpp
void Session::on_handshake(beast::error_code ec)
{
    if (ec)
        return fail(ec, "handshake");

    ws.async_read(buffer, beast::bind_front_handler(&Session::on_read, shared_from_this()));
}
```

And the on_read function:

```cpp
void Session::on_read(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transfered)
{
    boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transfered);

    if (ec)
        return fail(ec, "read");

    std::cout << "Got message" << std::endl;
    onMessage(Message::parseMessage(beast::buffers_to_string(buffer.data())));
    ws.async_read(buffer, beast::bind_front_handler(&Session::on_read, shared_from_this()));
}
```

And the on_write function:

```cpp
void Session::on_write(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transfered)
{
    boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transfered);

    if (ec)
        return fail(ec, "write");

    queue.erase(queue.begin());

    if (!queue.empty())
    {
        ws.async_write(net::buffer(queue.front()->toString()), beast::bind_front_handler(&Session::on_write, shared_from_this()));
    }
}
```

C# Program(For testing):

```cs
[DllImport(@"/data/cpp_projects/whatsapp_web_library/build/Debug/libWhatsApp_Web_Library.so")]
public static extern void OpenConnection(string id);
[DllImport(@"/data/cpp_projects/whatsapp_web_library/build/Debug/libWhatsApp_Web_Library.so")]
public static extern void CloseConnection(string id);
[DllImport(@"/data/cpp_projects/whatsapp_web_library/build/Debug/libWhatsApp_Web_Library.so")]
public static extern void GenerateQRCode(string id);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   string id = "test";
   OpenConnection(id);
   GenerateQRCode(id);
}
```

Now is my question, how can i implement this?
I have been stuck on this problem for 3 days now and am slowly despairing.

Thanks already :)

Comment: It would be more helpful if you show us some code

Comment: Code snippets added

Comment: Does this answer your question? [boost::asio::read function hanging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36678534/boostasioread-function-hanging)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `async_read_some` instead of `async_read`

From boost

> async_read_some function is used to asynchronously read data from the stream socket. The function call always returns immediately.
>
> The read operation may not read all of the requested number of bytes.
>   Consider using the async_read function if you need to ensure that the
>   requested amount of data is read before the asynchronous operation
>   completes.

Basically a successful call to `async_read_some` may read just one byte,
or it may fill the whole buffer, or anywhere in between. The
`asio::async_read` function, on the other hand, can be used to ensure that the entire
buffer is filled before the operation completes. The `async_write_some`
and `asio::async_write` functions have the same relationship.

[More about async_read_some](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_read_some.html)

Here is a good [example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp) of how to use `async_read_some`